# print everything from an option with md-select angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi everyone I am trying to learn angularjs.

I have made this select:

```
<label class="md-title" for="yachtId">Choose:</label>
 <select name="yachtId" id="yachtId" ng-options="selectedYacht.title for 
    selectedYacht in yachtIds.availableOptions track by selectedYacht.id" 
    ng-model="yachtIds.selectedOption" >
 </select>
```

I get my data in json format and it's like this:

```
$scope.yachtIds = {
availableOptions":[
     {"id":"2","title":"Name 1","maxCapacity":"5"},
     {"id":"7","title":"Name 2","maxCapacity":"8"}
 ]}
```

and with this line I get what the user selected:

```
  selectedYacht = {{yachtIds.selectedOption}}
```

the output is this: selectedYacht = {"id":"7","title":"Name 2","maxCapacity":"8"}

The problem is, I am trying to make the same select with md-select but I can't figure out how to print everything from the user's selection. With the below code, I get only the name.

```
<md-input-container flex="100">
  <label class="md-title" for="yachtId">Desired yacht:</label>
  <md-select ng-model="yachtIds.selectedOption"  name="yachtId" id="yachtId">
    <md-option ng-value="t.title" data-ng-repeat="t in yachtIds.availableOptions">
    {{ t.title }}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

So, the output is this: selectedYacht = Name 2, but I want it to be like the previous one (selectedYacht = {"id":"7","title":"Name 2","maxCapacity":"8"}).

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `ng-value` attribute to `t` instead of `t.title`, and add the `trackBy` model option:

```
<md-select ng-model="yachtIds.selectedOption" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}" name="yachtId" id="yachtId">
    <md-option ng-value="t" data-ng-repeat="t in yachtIds.availableOptions">
        {{ t.title }}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: And is there a better way to display the selected than using selectedYacht = {{yachtIds.selectedOption}} ? Maybe something that could possibly hold  more selected values, from different inputs?

Comment: So, I made an alternation and now it displays everything containing in the form, but I cannot make it work for checkbox.

Here is the codepen if anyone interested: http://codepen.io/arteewtf/pen/KgLKJV

I am open to suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you expecting same but i believe i would be helful

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in records">{{x.id}}-{{x.title}}-{{x.maxCapacity}}</li>
</ul>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
     {"id":"2","title":"Name 1","maxCapacity":"5"},
     {"id":"7","title":"Name 2","maxCapacity":"8"}
  ];
});
</script>
```